# ManyToMany Association with different TargetEntities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

So I have a Media entity which can be referenced from different target entities "Event", "Category", "Page", etc.

Right now i just have multiple @ManyToMany associations in my Media Entity, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Event", mappedBy="medias")
 */
private $events;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="medias")
 */
private $features;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="medias")
 */
private $categories;
```

And in the target entity i've got something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Media", inversedBy="events")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="events_medias")
 */
private $medias;
```

This results in many join tables in my database that look like this:

```
Table "public.events_medias"
  Column  |  Type   | Modifiers
----------+---------+-----------
 media_id | integer | not null
 event_id | integer | not null
```

I don't really like this, it makes the database really bulky and complicated.
I'd like to do all these associations with one table where the class of the target entity is persisted. Something like this:

```
Table "public.medias_entities"
  Column      |  Type   | Modifiers
--------------+---------+-----------
 media_id     | integer | not null
 entity_id    | integer | not null
 entity_class | string  | not null
```

Is this possible with doctrine and if so, what about the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance).

You should create superclass `MediaType` to be mediator between `Media` and end entities:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_class", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"event" = "Event", "feature" = "Feature", "category" = "Category"})
 */
class MediaType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Media", inversedBy="mediaType")
     */
    protected $medias;
}

/** @Entity */
class Event extends MediaType
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Category extends MediaType
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Feature extends MediaType
{
    // ...
}
```